# How to make a hoverable drop-down navigation menu with multiple sub-menus?

Tags: html, css

I was practicing to make a hoverable drop-down navigation bar with multiple sub-menus.

Here's the [code][1] for what I did.

[1]:

```css
header {
  background: #333;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

.navlogo {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}

.navbar .menu li {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

.navbar .menu li a,
.navbar .menu li .submenu li a,
.navbar .menu li .submenu li .subsubmenu li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar .menu li .submenu {
  display: none;
}

.navbar .menu li:hover .submenu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #333;
  top: 100%;
}

.navbar .menu li:hover .submenu li .subsubmenu {
  display: none;
}

.navbar .menu li:hover .submenu li:hover .subsubmenu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #333;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar" id="navbar">
    <ul class="menu" id="menu">
      <li>
        <a href=""><img src="" alt="Home" id="navlogo"></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Android</a>
        <ul class="submenu" id="submenu">
          <li><a href="">Tricks</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Solved Problems</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Windows</a>
        <ul class="submenu" id="submenu">
          <li><a href="">Tricks</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Solved Problems</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Linux</a>
        <ul class="submenu" id="submenu">
          <li><a href="">Tricks</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Solved Problems</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Gaming</a>
        <ul class="submenu" id="submenu">
          <li>
            <a href="">Android</a>
            <ul class="subsubmenu" id="subsubmenu">
              <li><a href="">Gameplay</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Walkthroughs</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Tips</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Reviews</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">Windows</a>
            <ul class="subsubmenu" id="subsubmenu">
              <li><a href="">Gameplay</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Walkthroughs</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Tips</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Reviews</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">Linux</a>
            <ul class="subsubmenu" id="subsubmenu">
              <li><a href="">Tips</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="">iOS</a></li>
        </ul>

      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Entertainment</a>
        <ul class="submenu" id="submenu">
          <li>
            <a href="">Movies</a>
            <ul class="subsubmenu" id="subsubmenu">
              <li><a href="">Reviews</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Downloads</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">Shows</a>
            <ul class="subsubmenu" id="subsubmenu">
              <li><a href="">Reviews</a></li>
              <li><a href="">Downloads</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Education</a>
        <ul class="submenu" id="submenu">
          <li><a href="">Programming</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Maths</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Science</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Mental Ability</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Languages</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Ask</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**Problems**

1. All the sub-menu links on hover are displaying in one place only instead of displaying below the hovered link.
2. I am not able to style the sub-menus correctly. Like how to make **Solved Problems** link appear in one line. And then except **Android's Sub menu** all other are displaying as **inline**(I think!).
3. How to make the spacing look like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown.asp) ? Basically I want my sub-menus to look like the style given in the shared tutorial.

Comment: `.navbar .menu li:hover .submenu { left: 0; }` would get you most of the way there.

Comment: @Turnip They are coming below that but in a very weird way.

Comment: [codepen link](https://codepen.io/pragyan52yadav/pen/QWyENZp).